# How to add trailingshlash to redirect IF NOT already there in .htaccess (while pointing to new domain)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I migrated to a new domain so I would like all old url's point to the exact same page on the new url. Therefore I only have this code in my .htaccess file and this is doing what I would like it to do:

RewriteEngine on Redirect 301 / https://meditatieinstituut.nl/

But some old links with value does not have a trailing slash and the redirect to the trailing slash will only be made on the new domain. Therefore there is 1 more redirect than neccessary.
For example check this url in [httpstatus.io](https://httpstatus.io/):
http://www.vihara.nl/bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie

So I would like:
http://www.vihara.nl/bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie

NOT TO REDIRECT FIRST TO:
http://www.meditatieinstituut.nl/bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie

BUT DIRECTLY TO:
http://www.meditatieinstituut.nl/bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie/

**So to redirect to the new domain WITH already with the trailing at the end.**

**But this should only be done if there is no trailingslash at the end.**

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: First of all, the Redirect directive is not part of mod_rewrite, so you don’t need `RewriteEngine on` here, if you use only that. Second, you will have to use a regular expression here, so RedirectMatch instead. Try `RedirectMatch "(.*)/?$" "https://meditatieinstituut.nl/$1/"` - the slash at the end of the pattern is optional and not part of the capture group, and in the target URL we just add a slash at the end in any case.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. It almost done the trick, but now this url http://www.vihara.nl/bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie/ is redirecting to:
https://meditatieinstituut.nl//bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie// So wit double //. I changed it back now, but maybe you know how I could prevent this from happening?

Comment: Okay, the greediness of regular expressions appears to make it match the full URL including the last slash with `.*` here, and then it goes, nope, no optional trailing slash after that. Try `"(.*[^/])/?$"` instead - this demands that the last character inside the capture group is not a slash, and then allows for an optional one after that. (Check if just the base URL still redirects properly as well with that.)

Comment: (And if it works, add the status code `301` back in. Right now, without one specified, it implicitly uses 302, which is good for testing, but afterwards you want those redirects to be permanent again.)

Comment: Almost there I believe ;-) It's now redirecting to: //bewustwording/hoe-moet-je-mediteren-uitleg-vipassana-meditatie/ 
So the double trailing slash on the end of the line is gone, but there is still one in the beginning of the url.

Comment: Does someone kwow how to fix the final step? We're almost there but I have no clue...